# Conversão de Hex para Decimal utilizando Complemento de Dois

Tags: c#, gps

Preciso converter uma string `HEX` para `decimal`, a `string` utiliza o padrão Complemento de Dois e `IEEE-754` para definir a quantidade de casas decimais

É um sistema de rastreamento, de acordo com o manual a `string` `C1B6DF66` corresponde a `-22,8590813` e `C23C1762` corresponde a `-47,0228348`.

```
var fb = Convert.ToUInt32(hx,16);
var twosComp2 = (~fb + 1);
var y= BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)twosComp2), 0);
```

Estou utilizando o código acima mas não consigo chegar ao mesmo resultado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encontrei a solução:

```
public static Single ConvertHexToSingle (string hexVal) 
{
      try 
      {
          int i=0, j=0;
          byte[] bArray = new byte[4];
          for (i = 0; i <= hexVal.Length-1; i += 2) 
          {
              bArray[j] = Byte.Parse (hexVal[i].ToString() + hexVal[i + 1].ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
              j += 1;
          }
          Array.Reverse (bArray);
          Single s =  BitConverter.ToSingle (bArray, 0);
          return (s);
      } 
      catch (Exception ex) {
          throw new FormatException ("The supplied hex value is either empty or in an incorrect format.  Use the " +
              "following format: 00000000", ex);
      }
  }
```

Funcionando:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string valor = "C1B6DF66";

    Single s = ConvertHexToSingle(valor);

    Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
}
```

> Resultado: ***-22.85908***

Coloquei no [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PpSLT8)

Fonte: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/99483/Convert-value-by-IEEE-protocol